# In javascript, is it bad practice to attach custom events to the document itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I have a number of bootstrap modals that contain very small forms (2 fields max). Because they are very similar in what they do, they all use a jQuery plugin I wrote to do the saving of the forms they contain (the plugin does other things before saving as well, but that's irrelevant).

These modals are "embedded" in multiple places. I want to have an easy way to determine, from other parts of the code, whether a saving occurred. Because the saving is abstracted from the code that would be interested in knowing when it occurs, I was thinking of changing the saving plugin to trigger custom events bound to document and then writing event handlers like document.on('my-event-here'... whenever I'm interested to know whether a saving occurred.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a bad practice since it's a custom event. If it were instead a click event, that would be bad practice because it would be triggered more often that it's needed.

Comment: It doesn't sound like bad practice but it's maybe a slightly unconventional approach to avoiding the need for a function in the global namespace. You might consider the [Module Pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) instead.

Comment: There is a small advantage of binding to the innermost element that you can -- it reduces the chance of collisions should someone else try to use the same event name.  If this is a small project, with a single developer, then it isn't really an issue.  With large projects, you may need to take extra care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not consider it a "bad practice" per se, however I would use the plugin itself to provide this functionality. For example

```
$("#selector").customPlugin( customOptions );  // initialize the plugin


$.customPlugin.on("save", function(evt, data) {
    // event called on save, where data contains anything relevant
});
//$.customPlugin.off("save", ...);
```

And I would use a custom element inside the plugin to to the actual event manager :

```
var customElement = $("<div>");

// adding/removing a (new) callback
customElement.on("save", saveCallback);
customElement.off("save", saveCallback);

// triggering an event
customElement.trigger("save", data);
```

It is better practice to encapsulate whatever your plugin needs... inside the plugin and not create unnecessary dependancies; everything should evolve around your plugin.